# Limit the number of selectable locales

Tags: flutter, dart, localization

Here is [a line of code](https://github.com/flutter/gallery/blob/bd531c49341b93a6e2417d5e27820ef4a19d587f/lib/data/gallery_options.dart#L70) which returns the locale:

```
// lib/data/gallery_options.dart

Locale get locale => _locale ?? deviceLocale;
```

... which can be accessed like:

```
// lib\studies\shrine\app.dart

locale: GalleryOptions.of(context).locale,
```

The problem is the options for locales, i.e. `supportedLocales` come from this file:

`.dart_tool/flutter_gen/gen_l10n/gallery_localizations.dart`

[image: Screenshot]

... which looks to be *not* part of the repository and automatically generated. It is *not* editable and gets reloaded discarding all changes.

How can I limit the number of locales selectable by the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!  Supported locales of **settings** page are on file `lib/pages/settings.dart` and can be limited by modifying [this line](https://github.com/flutter/gallery/blob/00c8404ee13ab1383fca94daaeb70f156701d707/lib/pages/settings.dart#L124) with this patch:

```dart
-    var supportedLocales =
-        List<Locale>.from(GalleryLocalizations.supportedLocales);
+    var supportedLocales = [
+      const Locale('en'),
+      const Locale('he'),
+    ];
     supportedLocales.removeWhere((locale) => locale == deviceLocale);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Update

This approach is not stable. The locales are regenerated again.

---

The way to remove locales is to use:

`Tools > Flutter Intl > Remove Locale`

[image: Tools menu]

Or by just simply removing unwanted `*.arb` files:

[image: arb files]